# Can You Use AnkhSVN and TortoiseSVN at the Same Time?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

When I attempt to use the above two tools together with Visual Studio 2010, after I open visual studio the tab "Pending Changes" contains the text "Team Foundation Server is not your current Source Control plug-in.  Click here to set the current Source Control plug-in."

When I click on this message, it opens the Options dialog that shows as the current source-control plug-in "AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio", so why would it be giving me that error message?  The reason I ask about TortoiseSVN is that AnkhSVN has work occasionally in the past, but I think what has happened is that after using TortoiseSVN to commit changes, then AnkhSVN no longer works.  Here are the versions of TortoiseSVN and AnkhSVN that I am presently using:

AnkhSVN: 2.1.8420.8
TortoiseSVN: 1.6.8.19260 (32 bit)

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Is there some special XML code that specifies the SCM that needs to be in the solution file?  TIA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you might have opened the wrong "Pending changes" window - have you opened the TFS one not the Ankh one?

Comment: That was it!  There is a "Pending Changes" that is the third item down in the View menu, and another one in the "Other Windows"->"Pending Changes."  The funny thing is that they both open the AnkhSVN "Pending Changes", while the TFS "Pending Changes" window is simply the one that opens automatically when loading VS 2010.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Roger: Visual Studio SCC providers are supposed to hide their inactive commands when the SCC provider is not active. If you enable TFS you would see their Pending Changes menu commands and not AnkhSVN's.

Comment: Thanks, this actually solved my problem too. I had the same problem for Visual SoureSafe.  I had chosen Pending Changes instead of Pending Checkins.